# Can't change my ImageView to data retrieved from stream in Swift

Tags: python, swift, uiimageview, buffer, twisted

I'm trying to retrieve a picture over an inputstream and then set my ImageView to that picture. Below is my code for how to retrieve the inputstream and read the data.

```
 let bufferSize = 1024
    var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)

    while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable){
        let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
        if(len > 0){
            let imageData = NSData(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count)
            print("\(imageData)")
            let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
            ImageView.image = newImage
        }
    }
```

I'm using the CFStream as sockets for receiving data. All of this works fine as I'm able to send and receive all my other data but for some reason the picture doesn't.

Many thanks.

UPDATE.

The code from below doesn't throw any errors but the picture is still not showing. Is there anything wrong with my server code?

```
        f = open("/home/pi/Documents/server/foo.jpg", "rb")
        byte = f.read()
        print "Done reading"
        self.transport.write(byte)
        f.close()
        print "Done sending"
```

The server code is written in Twisted Python and the connection is working accordingly since I'm able to transfer other messages than the picture.

Comment: `inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)` reads up to `buffer.count` (= 1024) bytes. Is your image smaller that 1024 bytes?

Comment: No but it keeps reading until the inputStream is empty, right?

Comment: In your code, you keep reading from the inputStream, but you are trying to construct your image with each data fragment which is less than or equal to 1024 bytes. You may need to accumulate all data fragments into one data, and after reading all data fragments, you need to convert the accumulated data (not the last data fragment) into UIImage.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I've been trying to do but I only get problem with unwrapping the data.

I need to save the accumulated data as Data in order to set the new image but how do I declare a variable that can read all the data?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to show you an example as an answer. But reading binary data from stream can cause variety of problems. So, take it as a starting point to fix your issue.

Comment: Please see my update. Is there another way to save the accumulated data in order to not mess with the data?

Comment: Got it, I'll combine your code into my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to accumulate the data fragment into one Data, you need to write something like this:

```
    let bufferSize = 1024
    var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
    //You need to assign an actual Data to the variable.
    //With initial value given, you have no need to work with Optionals.
    var imageData = Data()
    while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable){
        let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
        if(len > 0){
            imageData.append(&buffer, count: buffer.count)
        }
    }
    //You need to try converting the data to image after reading all data fragments.
    let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
    pictureView.image = newImage
```

If you find other issues with this code, please report as comments to this answer.

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors but the picture is empty. I have tried to see if there is anything wrong with my server code but I can't find any mistakes. I'll upload my server code as well, it's written with Twisted in Python

Comment: I do not know about Twisted Python, but what is the size of `byte` in your python code, and what is the length of the `imageData` just before converting to UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was not sending each byte of the file. When i changed my server code to:

```
with open("/home/pi/Documents/server/foo.jpg", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read()
    print "Done reading"
    while byte:
        self.transport.write(byte)
        byte = f.read(1)
    print "Done sending"
f.close()
```

It worked fine. However, I will accept the answer below because it might have been a problem with how I was reading my data into the new image file as well.